# AngularJS pagination showing all items instead of page items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to paginate some items. All the items are shown instead of only the items for the current page.

**Controller:**

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.tickets = [];
        $scope.bodynews = [];
        var begin;
        var end;

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'getNews.json'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.tickets = data;
            $scope.noOfPages =Math.floor($scope.tickets.news[0].allNews.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
            for (i=0; i< $scope.tickets.news[0].allNews.length; i++){

                $scope.bodynews[i] =  $scope.tickets.news[0].allNews[i].bodyNews;

                }
                begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
                end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });


        $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
          $scope.paged = {
            bodynews: $scope.bodynews.slice(begin, end)
          }
        });

    });
```

```
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <div>{{noOfPages}} &nbsp; {{currentPage}} &nbsp; {{maxSize}}
            <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="bodynews.length" items-per-page="5"></pagination>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-info" ng-repeat="tic in bodynews">
            {{tic}}
        </div>

    </body>
```

Here is the PLNKR demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Tnf8j8h3igaR3mAc9Yqf?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? It will be easy to spot the problem.

Comment: you want to limit the number of results?

Comment: @Surya i updated the answer with the plunker! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the paginated `$scope` property in your `ng-repeat`. You're using `$scope.bodynews`, but you have set `$scope.paged.bodynews` to the items for the page:

```
$scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
  $scope.paged = {
    bodynews: $scope.bodynews.slice(begin, end)
  };
});
```

So, change your markup to:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" ng-repeat="tic in paged.bodynews">
```

[**Working demo.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mtw76pLY4z1pIzufA49i?p=preview)

Comment: @FabioEnne You need to change `$scope.itemsPerPage = 22` and your markup should be `items-per-page=itemsPerPage` so that you only have to write `22` in one place and the other will automatically be the same. http://plnkr.co/edit/2c1Yv4Jp3EtGSZK6trF8?p=preview